# When to use rustc 'target-cpu' setting?

Tags: rust, llvm

I'm learining Rust and want to build app that will run on another server, however, server's `target` is the same as local/CI.
I found there is a way to specify `target-cpu` property for compilier.
I tried to build for `target-cpu=skylake` (local) and for `target-cpu=skylake-avx512` (server) and noticed slight difference in output binary size.
Will building for a specific CPU improve performance or change application behaviour?

Comment: Most likely there are either extra op codes of a different CPU that aren't standard to x86/ARM which allow for improved speed or accounts for different speeds of similar operations to choose the most efficient. I don't think it would change application behavior (unless different things are done based on the time it takes to do something).

Comment: In my opinion you should use it when performance is more critical than portability, you know the platform ahead of time, and benchmarks show a performance gain. Be careful, you can invoke UB if you get the target cpu wrong.

Comment: To answer your last question more directly: you'd need to benchmark to know if performance is better with a different target cpu, and the behavior should remain the same unless you invoke undefined behavior (undefined behavior might change platform to platform! It might "work" on one platform, and might do bad things on another platform).